# Need to "Prettify" Xaml: Convert a long PathGeometry "Figures" attribute string to XML syntax

Tags: xml, xaml, pretty-print

I have a whole lot of icons that I am using in my application.  I've got them in a XAML Resource dictionary at PathGeometry objects with the figures specified in attribute syntax, like this:

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="RunPathGeometry" 
              Figures="M56.11 46.17 69.2 33.09a25.29 25.29 0 1 0 4.41 27H85.16l.1 0q-.25.91-.57 1.8A36.32 36.32 0 1 1 77 25.3l8.92-8.92V46.17Z" 
              FillRule="NonZero"
              />
```

Now this works just fine but some of these icons are so complicated and the attribute strings so long that I have -- literally -- over 30,000 columns of text.

I would very much prefer to have these expressed in property syntax, if only because it would give me a ton of *lines* instead of a *columns*.  Lines I can live with (and there would certainly be a lot less then 30,000...)

Is there some simple method/converter anyone know of that would do this for me?  Perhaps where I could paste in the PathGeometry in one format and get it out in another?

Skimming the docs it looks like I could likely write one myself with XamlReader/XamlWriter but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel and burn all the cycles to do this if someone has already...

Edited -- since someone asked, What I mean by "Property" syntax is where the figures are expressed in closed XML tags rather than in attributes.  something like this example below (It's actually for a simple triangle example but more complicated shapes can be expressed as well.)

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="10,100">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                <LineSegment Point="100,100" />
                                <LineSegment Point="100,50" />
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: What's "property syntax"?

Comment: Where each internal element is expressed in closed xml tags.   I have a PathGeometry tag which contains a PathFigureCollection Tag which contains PathFigure Tags each of which contains PathFigure.Segments tag, which contains a PathSegmentCollectionTag which then contains LineSegment tags (or ArcSegment, BezierSegment, etc).  Verbose?  Definitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've got a bunch of these in a resource dictionary and we've been very happy with it:

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="SearchGlyphPathGeometry" x:Shared="True" FillRule="EvenOdd">
    <PathGeometry.Figures>
        M 25,13
        A 12,12, 0,1,1, 13,25
        A 12,12, 0,0,1, 25,13
        Z
        M 35.8,41.8
        A 20,20, 0,0,1, 5,25
        A 20,20, 0,1,1, 41.8,35.8
        L 57,51
        L 51,57
        Z
    </PathGeometry.Figures>
</PathGeometry>
```

Use like so:

```
<Path Data="{StaticResource SearchGlyphPathGeometry}" Fill="DeepSkyBlue" />
```

It would be simple enough to use perl or sed to insert linebreaks in front of every alpha character in a path string. Or C#:

```
var re = new Regex("([a-z])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var s = re.Replace(PathGeometryText, "\n\t\t\t$1");
```

You could write code to recursively search your project directory for XAML files, look for `PathGeometry` elements, transform the `Figures` attribute value with the above regex, remove the attribute, and add a child element instead:

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="RunPathGeometry" FillRule="NonZero">
    <PathGeometry.Figures>

        M56.11 46.17 69.2 33.09
        a25.29 25.29 0 1 0 4.41 27
        H85.16
        l.1 0
        q-.25.91-.57 1.8
        A36.32 36.32 0 1 1 77 25.3
        l8.92-8.92
        V46.17
        Z 
    </PathGeometry.Figures>
</PathGeometry>
```

I'd also [do something about that mildly annoying orphan newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_May) the regex leaves in front of the text.

For your original idea, you could write some trivial C# code to instantiate `PathGeometry` instances from your strings and serialize them as XAML, but the above seems to me to be at least as readable, and less work besides.

Comment: Hey thanks, this is  basically what I am trying to do.     I admit, I did not know that I could embed the the path-figure syntax like that -- as just raw values separated by newlines inside of a "Figures" tag.  I thought it had to be in a quoted string on a single line.  This will vastly simplify the readability.  But is still leaves me with the question:  How do I convert my 30,000 character path figure syntax string to something like this.  I sure wouldn't want to do it manually, even if I only had the one icon!  Again, I'm sure I can write it, I was hoping someone already had...

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  Sed and regular expressions have always been one of those things that I really want to master but never have the time.  I always learn just enough to get my task done and move on to other things.  I spent the last hour struggling with Sed and getting the right options and managed to get something similarly working.  This is my sed script:  which appears to do the job

s/([MmLlHhVvCcQqSsTtAa])([^MmLlHhVvCcQqSsTtAa])/\n\1 \2/g

Comment: Frankly, the knowledge that I could just embed the commands inside one tag on multiple lines was huge for me.  Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @Joe For that sed thing, I'd just do `s/([a-z])/\n\1/gi`. `i` flag at the end for case insensitive. Any alpha character gets a newline; they're all commands. Not that actually matters in this case if you miss one anyway.